# How can I free memory when I misuse interval Observable?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, rxjs, observable

This code maintains the four instances of `BigClass` alive, as shows a memory dump in Chrome. The `interval` `Observable` stays alive and maintains the callbacks alive which have references on the instances of `BigClass`.

```js
class BigClass {
    constructor(observable) {
        this.bigArray = new Array(9999999).fill(0);
        observable.subscribe(x => this.result = x);
    }
    //...
}

let observable = new rxjs.interval(1000);
let bigObject = new BigClass(observable);
let bigObject1 = new BigClass(observable);
let bigObject2 = new BigClass(observable);
let bigObject3 = new BigClass(observable);

bigObject = null;
bigObject1 = null;
bigObject2 = null;
bigObject3 = null;
observable = null;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

How can I free memory in this case when I have no more references on the subscriptions neither on the source `Observable`?

Answer (score 1):

For every `.subscribe` you must manually call `.unsubscribe` to cancel execution and free up resources. To make this process easier, try to keep everything as observable and avoid subscribing manually. Usually it is better when done by your framework, template engine, etc.

For more information take a look at the documentation about [Disposing Observable Executions](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable#disposing-observable-executions)

Comment: My question is more about: is there a way to free memory after my code has run?

Comment: Automatically (similar to C++ destructors) - no. (For future there is a [Stage 3 EMCAScript proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-weakrefs#finalizers)). But, if you [structure your code "reactively"](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/e581baffb3db3e4f749350326af32de8d5ba4363/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f4149696d5138432e6a7067), as described in answer, you will not need to subscribe manually so often.